# Iterate over List of Map in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a List that contains a map like this:

```
Map<String, Long> count = new HashMap<>();
count.put("totalMessageCount", 5L);         
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> names = new HashMap<>();
names.put("someKey", count);
List<Map<String, Map<String, Long>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(names);
```

I am sending this list from controller to the View.

I have tried this:

```
<table>
        <tr th:each="element : ${list}">
        <td th:text="${element.key}"></td>
        <td th:text="${element.value}"></td>
</table>
```

I get an error:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'key' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public or not valid?
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
> at
> ...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `list` is a list of `Map` objects, not map `Entry` objects, so `element` is misnamed.

Comment: after 2 hours I finally understood what you meant. Okay thanks now I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another level of nesting, most probably.

```
<table>
    <th:block th:each="map : ${list}">
       <tr th:each="e : ${map}">
          <td th:text="${e.key}"></td>
          <td th:text="${e.value}"></td>
       </tr>
    </th:block>
</table>
```

As `key` and `value` are properties of a `Map.Entry`.